# What is the difference between assigning a string pointer first to allocated memory and directly to a string literal?

Tags: c

So my understanding is that these two block of codes are valid and do the same thing.

1.)

```
char *ptr = malloc(5);
ptr = "hi";
```

2.)

```
char *ptr = "hi";
```

I would want to know the difference between the two like if there any advantages of one over the other.

Comment: Difference: memory leak in 1st case.

Comment: The first version has a memory leak. The second one doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

The former is a bug, and that code should never have been written.

It overwrites the pointer returned by `malloc()` with the address of a string literal, dropping the original pointer and leaking memory.

You must use `strcpy()` or some other memory-copying method to initialize newly allocated heap memory with a string.

The second just assigns the (run-time constant) address of the string literal to the pointer `ptr`, no characters are copied anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The first bit is a possible memory leak, the second relies on the implicit `const` storage class being used, and assigns the memory address of an immutable string to a pointer.
Basically:

```
char *ptr = malloc(5);//allocates 5 * sizeof *ptr
//then assigns the address where this block starts to ptr
//this:
ptr = "hi";//assigns position of 'h','i', '\0' in read-only mem to ptr
```

Now, the address you've allocated, that `ptr` pointed to, still is allocated. The difference is that you have no *"handle"* on it anymore, because `ptr`'s value changed. There's no pointer pointing to the dynamic memory you allocated using `malloc`, so it's getting rather tricky to manage the memory... You probably won't be able to `free` it, and calling `free` on `ptr` now will result in undefined behaviour.
If you write:

```
char *ptr = "hi";
```

Then you're actually writing:

```
const char *ptr = "hi";
```

Which means you can't change the string to which `ptr` points:

```
ptr[0] = 'H';//IMBOSSIBRU
```

Alternatives are:

```
char string[] = "Hi";//copies Hi\0 to string
//or
char *ptr = malloc(5);
strcpy(ptr, "hi");//requires string.h
```

The difference between the two snippets above is that the first creates a stack array, the second allocates a block of memory on the heap. Stack memory is easier to manage, faster and just better in almost every way, apart from it being less abundant, and not really usable as a return value...

Comment: I wish you'd have made the comment say `//IMBOSSIBRU`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Only because you asked: made the edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a pool of string literals for every process. Whenever you create a string literal inside your code, the literal is saved in the pool and the string's address (i.e. an address pointing somewhere to the pool) is returned. Therefore, you are creating a memory leak in your first option, because you are overwriting the address you received with malloc.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case

```
char *ptr = malloc(5);
ptr = "hi";
```

There is a memory leak and later you are pointing ptr to a string literal "hi" which does require any memory from the heap (that's why there is memory leak).

But if you are allocating the memory and if you are using

```
strcpy (ptr, "hi");
```

then if you wish you can modify it

```
strcpy (ptr, "hello")
```

with one condition that you allocate sufficient memory before.

But in your case you are assigning a pointer *ptr* with a string literal, here you will not be able to modify it

```
ptr = "hello"            // not valid. This will give a segmentation fault error
```

In your second case there is no memory leak and you are making a pointer to point to a string literal and thus it's value cannot be modified as it will be stored in read only data segment.

Comment: To be clear, the assignment `ptr = "hello";` doesn't cause a segfault, but an attempt to modify whatever `ptr` points to (i.e. `ptr[2] = 'X';`) *can* cause it.